# Highlighting code window of visual studio based on line number using VSPackage

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-studio, c#-4.0, vspackage, visual-studio-sdk

I'm building a VSpackage extension to create "VisualStudio Tool Window".
I have a grid inside tool window, consisting of numbers. If a user selects a particular row of the grid. That particular line of code should be highlighted.

To be more clear,
Suppose my grid contains:

row 1 - 10,
row 2 - 15,
row 3 - 14,

if user selects row 1, then 10th line in the code window should get highlighted.
Is this feature possible using VisualStudio package. I have a strong feeling that this is possible.Because most of the search results work that way.

Any help on the same is greatly appreciated!!

Answer (score 0):

I finally found the answer to my post based on lot of googling. Hope this helps for others.

You need to use "TextSelection" class to highlight the above code line.

```
        foreach (CodeElement codeElement in projectItem.FileCodeModel.CodeElements)// search for the function to be opened
        {
            // get the namespace elements
            if (codeElement.Kind == vsCMElement.vsCMElementNamespace)
            {
                foreach (CodeElement namespaceElement in codeElement.Children)
                {
                    // get the class elements
                    if (namespaceElement.Kind == vsCMElement.vsCMElementClass || namespaceElement.Kind == vsCMElement.vsCMElementInterface)
                    {
                        foreach (CodeElement classElement in namespaceElement.Children)
                        {
                            try
                            {
                                // get the function elements to highlight methods in code window
                                if (classElement.Kind == vsCMElement.vsCMElementFunction)
                                {
                                    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(highlightString))
                                    {
                                        if (classElement.Name.Equals(highlightString, StringComparison.Ordinal))
                                        {
                                            classElement.StartPoint.TryToShow(vsPaneShowHow.vsPaneShowTop, null);

                        classElement.StartPoint.TryToShow(vsPaneShowHow.vsPaneShowTop, null);

                            // get the text of the document
                         EnvDTE.TextSelection textSelection = window.Document.Selection as EnvDTE.TextSelection;

                            // now set the cursor to the beginning of the function
                            textSelection.MoveToPoint(classElement.StartPoint);
                            textSelection.SelectLine();

                                        }
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                            catch
                            {
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use simpler solution; see below

```
  int lineNo = 3;
  if (!isProjectItemOpen)
  {
       Window win = projectItem.Open();
       win.Visible = true;
       Document doc = win.Document;
       doc.Activate();
       var ts = dte.ActiveDocument.Selection;
       ts.GotoLine(lineNo, true);
  }
```